# Cucumber - Unable to run tests using runner

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Issue:
When trying to run the cucumber runner class in order to test specifics tests (by tag), the tests will not run. The following messages will be received:

```
    Feature: Homepage

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

  @Testone
  Scenario: whateves     # Homepage_TC.feature:4
    Given printsomething

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
1 Steps (1 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^printsomething$")
public void printsomething() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Running the feature file will work just fine. Below you can find the runner.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/INGPSD2/main/resources/",
                 format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber",},
                glue = "src/INGPSD2/test/java/Steps",
                 tags = {"@Testone"})
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class runnerCucumber { }
```

Hooks class:

```
public class Hooks {
private static List<DriverFactory> webDriverThreadPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DriverFactory>());
private static ThreadLocal<DriverFactory> driverFactory;
public SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

@Before
public static void instantiateDriverObject() {
    driverFactory = new ThreadLocal<DriverFactory>() {
        @Override
        protected DriverFactory initialValue() {
            DriverFactory driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
            webDriverThreadPool.add(driverFactory);
            return driverFactory;
        }
    };
}

public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
        return driverFactory.get().getDriver();

}

// ----------------- SETUP

// -----------------------

@After
public static void closeDriverObjects() throws Exception {
    getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
    for (DriverFactory driverFactory : webDriverThreadPool) {
        driverFactory.quitDriver();
    }
}
```

}

Please let me know if i can provide more information as this issue is really annoying and i couldnt find anything yet that could help.

Comment: Seems like the runner is unable the find the step definition for "Given printsomething". The glue on @CucumberOptions on the runner class should be the package name where the step definitions are located.

Comment: added 
glue = "src/INGPSD2/test/java/Steps/_GeneralSteps"
And still the same issue

Comment: try `glue = "INGPSD2/test/java/Steps"`?

Comment: @GeorgeCodreanu that is not the package name I was looking for. In which package is declared on the steps definitions class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake defining `glue`. You should use package name instead of path to `steps.java`.
So change 
`glue = "src/INGPSD2/test/java/Steps"` to `glue = "package_name"` where your class with steps is located.